# Using more that 1 argument in glob()

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, arguments, glob

I'm trying to recursively search files ending with .png or .jpg in a folder named 'dataset' using the glob(). Here is the code snippet:

```
    for imagePath in glob.glob(args["dataset"] + "/*.png"):
```

I'm setting the image ID using the imagePath inside the loop. How can I search using 2 arguments. I know ',' doesn't work as glob() accepts exactly one argument.

Comment: `glob` supports for simple shell-style wildcards.Try `glob.glob('*.[jp][pn]g')`.

Comment: @trdcaz but the result may include files with extension `.jng` and `.ppg`.  Try `glob.glob("*.jpg")+glob.glob("*.png")`.

Comment: @acw1668 Seriously, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could perhaps be to first create the list of existing files and then loop this list

```
image_types = (‘/*.jpg', ‘/*.png')
image_files = []
for files in image_types:
    image_files.extend(glob.glob("dataset/" + files))

image_files #list of .jpg and .png files
```

Comment: That's a really roundabout way of saying `image_files = glob.glob("dataset/*.jpg") + glob.glob("dataset/*.png")`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a couple of comments, `glob` returns a list, so you can simply concatenate the lists with `+`. Example:

```py
from glob import glob

for files in glob(args["dataset"] + "/*.png") + glob(args["dataset"] + "/*.jpg"):
    
    pass    # your file operations go here
```

Stylistically, you may want to use escaped newlines to prevent overly long lines:

```py
for files in glob(args["dataset"] + "/*.png") \
           + glob(args["dataset"] + "/*.jpg"):
    
    pass    # your file operations go here
```